# Disable log output to the Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, console

I am on Rails 5.2.2. Every time I log something in the Rails console, the text appears in the console. It's very annoying because some commands I use in that context dump tons of information into the logger. It pollutes my console. Is there a way to disable that behavior?
Note that I want to silence all the logs, not only the ActiveRecord ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there's no clean way of doing this. The solution that I have found is to create file named `config/initializers/disable_console_log.rb` and add the following content:

```
ActiveRecord::Railtie.instance_variable_set(:@load_console, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

add `;nil` after you command

`User.do_stuff;nil`

this will run the command and log `nil`

Comment: I am talking about the logger so the nil value at the end does not help.